# Set combobox selected item style when it has lots of items

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to set RED color for selected item in combobox control.
Here is a code how I achieve that:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App3.MainPage"
    xmlns:ui="using:App3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>

    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Name="grid">
        <ComboBox Name="cmb"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ComboBox.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6.5,8"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                                <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition From="Pressed" To="Normal">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid"/>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualTransition>
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid"/>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground"/>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedDisabled">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Grid x:Name="InnerGrid" Background="Transparent">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="PressedBackground" Fill="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Foreground="Red"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.Resources>
            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="ComboBoxItemStyle1"/>
            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Actually important part here is only

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Foreground="Red"/>
```

And it works like a charm, but only when combobox has few of items. When it has a lot of items they have default color.
For example:

```
this.cmb.DataContext = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
```

[image: Valid expanded combobox items color]
[image: Valid collapsed combobox item color]

works ok, but

```
this.cmb.DataContext = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
```

[image: Not valid expanded combobox items color]
[image: Not valid collapsed combobox item color]

does not work.
What is the reason it doesn't work when it has a lot of items?

Comment: Are you looking for `<ComboBox Name="cmb" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Foreground="Red" > ... rest of the code ...`? Can you precise when the item should be Red - when box is opened, after selection ended, pointer over or other?

Comment: @Romasz I need text to be red like on first two screenshots: when combobox is expanded or collapsed. I am ok about color used on third screenshot, but I still need text to be red on fourth screenshot.

Comment: @Geslot why don't you try to use a dataTemplate directly instead of using a style? simply define a dataTemplate and then design it the way you want

Comment: @AdityaSharma Thanks for advice Aditya, I'll try that today.

Comment: @AdityaSharma Thank you, this solution works!

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help. I am going to put an answer just so that you can accept it and the question gets closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way out to use a `DataTemplate` directly instead of using a style. simply define a `DataTemplate` and then design it the way you want. You can do this in two ways, defining the `DataTemplate` inLine i.e inside the Combobox control like below:

```
<Grid Name="grid">
<ComboBox Name="cmb"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Or if you're going to use the dataTemplate quite often in multiple controls or even going to change it a lot, put the DataTemplate in your `<Page>` tag and in the `ComboBox` simply set up a `StaticResource` something like below:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:key="MyComboBoxTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

So the updated Element XAML is:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmb"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate={StaticResource MyComboBoxTemplate}>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution is simple and beautiful.